Spring Security 6: Static Resources Not Loading on Login Page
I'm working on a Spring Boot application using Spring Security 6 and Java 17. My static resources (CSS, JS, images) are not loading on the login page. These resources are located under the resources directory inside the webapp folder of my application. I'm also using PrimeFaces 14.
Here is my
SecurityConfig.java
:
package com.leo.service-ui.configs.security; 

import java.util.Collections; 

import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager; 
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger; 
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value; 
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean; 
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration; 
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource; 
import org.springframework.core.io.FileSystemResource; 
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource; 
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager; 
import org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager; 
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity; 
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity; 
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity; 
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityCustomizer; 
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.AbstractHttpConfigurer; 
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain; 
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ExceptionMappingAuthenticationFailureHandler; 
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter; 

@EnableWebSecurity 
@Configuration 
public class SecurityConfig { 

    private static final Logger LOG = LogManager.getLogger(SecurityConfig.class); 

    @Bean 
    public CustomSpnegoEntryPoint customSpnegoEntryPoint() { 
        return new CustomSpnegoEntryPoint(); 
    } 

    @Bean 
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception { 
        LOG.info("SSO is disabled. Continuing using LDAP Authentication."); 
        http.csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable).authorizeHttpRequests((authz) -> authz.requestMatchers("/login") 
                .permitAll() 
                .anyRequest() 
                .permitAll()); 
        return http.build(); 
    } 

    @Bean 
    public WebSecurityCustomizer webSecurityCustomizer() { 
        return (web) -> web.ignoring() 
                .requestMatchers( 
                        "/images/**", 
                        "/js/**", 
                        "/css/**", 
                        "/webjars/**", 
                        "/resources/**", 
                        "/jakarta.faces.resource/**", 
                        "/jakarta.faces.resource/images/**"); 
    } 

} 

And here is my login.xhtml:
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head>
    <title>LEO TEST UI</title>
    <h:outputStylesheet name="css/style.css"/>
    <h:outputScript name="js/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"/>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery.noConflict()
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        //
        var url = window.location.pathname;
        var filename = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);

        if (filename.indexOf("login.xhtml") == -1) {
            window.location = "/service-ui/login.xhtml"
        }

        jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        });
        //
    </script>
</h:head>
<body>
<div class="container" style="width: 480px; position:absolute; top:50%;left:50%;margin-left:-240px; margin-top:-190px;">
    <div id="header">
        <h:graphicImage name="images/leo-logo.jpg"/>
        <div id="title">
            LEO Markets<br/>
            <b>SERVICE UI</b>
            <span><h:outputText value="#{homepageBean.environment}"/></span>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>

    <h:form id="form">
        <h:messages id="resultMsg" errorClass="error-message" infoClass="info-message"/>

        <div class="input-row">
            <div class="required">*</div>
            <h:outputLabel id="usernameLabel" for="username" value="Username:"/>
            <h:inputText id="username" styleClass="text" maxlength="255" value="#{loginBean.username}">
            </h:inputText>
            <p:message for="username"/>
        </div>
        <div class="input-row">
            <div class="required">*</div>
            <h:outputLabel id="passwordLabel" for="password" value="Password: "/>
            <h:inputSecret id="password" styleClass="text" maxlength="50" value="#{loginBean.password}">
            </h:inputSecret>
            <p:message for="password"/>
        </div>
        <div class="input-row">
            <div class="required">*</div>
            <h:outputLabel id="domainLabel" for="domain" value="Domain: "/>
            <h:selectOneMenu styleClass="text" id="domain" value="#{loginBean.domain}">
                <f:selectItems value="#{userManagementBean.domainList}"/>
            </h:selectOneMenu>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>

        <div style="margin-left: 160px; font-size: 11px; line-height: 22px; margin-bottom: 10px;">
            Use your Windows username/password to login.<br/>
            If you have not been explicitly granted access, you can still login but with restricted access.
        </div>

        <h:commandButton id="loginBtn" value="Login" class="submit-button" action="#{loginBean.login}"/>
    </h:form>

    <br/>
    <br/>
</div>
</body>
</html>

I've tried adding a WebSecurityCustomizer to allow access to these resources, but it doesn't seem to work. What am I missing?
Additional Information:

Spring Boot version: 6
Java version: 17
PrimeFaces version: 14

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Have you tried to concatenate the matchers and specify the HttpMethod to reduce the scope of the matcher, like this:
@Bean 
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception { 
    LOG.info("SSO is disabled. Continuing using LDAP Authentication."); 

    http.csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
        .authorizeHttpRequests(req -> req.requestMatchers("/login").permitAll())
        .authorizeHttpRequests(
            req ->
                req.requestMatchers(
                        HttpMethod.GET,
                        "/images/**",
                        "/js/**",
                        "/css/**",
                        "/webjars/**",
                        "/resources/**",
                        "/jakarta.faces.resource/**",
                        "/jakarta.faces.resource/images/**")
                    .permitAll());

    return http.build(); 
} 

Removing both the anyRequest().permitAll() and the definition of the WebSecurityCustomizer bean?

it blocked the access actually

Can you detail more the block? The login page is not reached, the authentication endpoint are not accessible, the authentication goes ok but the application is not loaded... And which is the call that blocks the access?
